# How do i copy a file from one windows machine to other windows machine folder using java

Tags: windows, file-transfer, file-copying

How do i copy a file from one windows machine to other windows machine folder using java

is it possible using jcraft library com.jcraft.jsch.JSch.JSch ?or jcraft only copy to linux unix machines.

can you please provide the code.

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try JCIFS: http://jcifs.samba.org/

"JCIFS is an Open Source client library that implements the CIFS/SMB networking protocol"

Here is an example.

http://sanjaal.com/java/875/java-utilities/java-tutorial-using-jcifs-to-copy-files-to-shared-network-drive-using-username-and-password/

Comment: thank you but where i need to mension ip address of destination machine.if i want to store in C directory what NETWORK_FOLDER i need to mension.give some example NETWORK_FOLDER for ip folder

Comment: You could use: NETWORK_FOLDER = "smb://10.0.1.1/shared/public/photos"

Comment: even for my system i get jcifs.smb.SmbAuthException:Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password.i have given smb://myip/Users/

Comment: USERNAME = "username";
PASSWORD = "password";
DOMAIN = "domain";
NETWORK_FOLDER = "smb://machineName/network_folder/";
auth = new NtlmPasswordAuthentication(DOMAIN, USERNAME, PASSWORD);path = NETWORK_FOLDER + fileName;
        sFile = new SmbFile(path, auth);
        sfos = new SmbFileOutputStream(sFile);
        sfos.write(fileContent.getBytes());